# asp:TextBox is not working inside asp:Placeholder C# sharepoint 2013

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, development, asp.net, html

I am trying to add some `TextBoxes` controls dynamically based on items in my database. This is my `asp:PlaceHolder` in `.aspx` page

```
 <asp:PlaceHolder ID="PlaceHolderHTML" runat="server"></asp:PlaceHolder>
```

and now from C# code I am trying to create dynamic `HTML` and then that html render to `asp:PlaceHolder`.

This is my C# code:

```
 StringBuilder data = new StringBuilder();
 foreach (SPListItem item in collitem)
 {
 data.Append(@"
      <tr>
          <th class='accordionSection esEmplCardSectionHeader'>
                <span id='lblSectionName'>
                    <asp:TextBox ID='TextBox" + item["ID"].ToString() + @"' runat='server'></asp:TextBox>
                </span>
          </th>             
      </tr>         
 }

 PlaceHolderHTML.Controls.Add(new Literal { Text = data.ToString() });
```

but in browser the `TextBox` controls are not being shown. When I inpect element the textbox I am seeing the following result:
[image]

So the `textbox` inside html that is being sent to `asp:PlaceHolder`, browser is not knowing it as asp control and in  the browser nothing is being shown, so how to solve this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code below for your reference:

```
SPList list = SPContext.Current.Web.Lists["ListC"];
SPListItemCollection collitem = list.Items;
this.PlaceHolderHTML1.Controls.Add(new Literal { Text = "<table>" });
foreach (SPListItem item in collitem)
{
    TextBox tb = new TextBox();
    tb.ID = "TextBox"+item["ID"].ToString();
    tb.Text = item["Title"].ToString();
    this.PlaceHolderHTML1.Controls.Add(new Literal { Text = "<tr><td class='accordionSection esEmplCardSectionHeader'>"});
    this.PlaceHolderHTML1.Controls.Add(new Literal { Text = "<span id='lblSectionName" + item["ID"].ToString() + "'>" });
    this.PlaceHolderHTML1.Controls.Add(tb);
    this.PlaceHolderHTML1.Controls.Add(new Literal { Text = "</span></td></tr>" });               
}
this.PlaceHolderHTML1.Controls.Add(new Literal { Text = "</table>" });
```

[image]

Or we can also use the code below:

```
SPList list = SPContext.Current.Web.Lists["ListC"];
SPListItemCollection collitem = list.Items;
StringBuilder data = new StringBuilder();
this.PlaceHolderHTML1.Controls.Add(new Literal { Text = "<table>" });
foreach (SPListItem item in collitem)
{
    data.Append("<tr><td class='accordionSection esEmplCardSectionHeader'>");
    data.Append("<span id='lblSectionName" + item["ID"].ToString() + "'>");
    data.Append("<input type='text' ID='TextBox"+item["ID"].ToString()+"' runat='server'/>");
    data.Append("</span></td></tr>");
}
this.PlaceHolderHTML1.Controls.Add(new Literal { Text = data.ToString() });
this.PlaceHolderHTML1.Controls.Add(new Literal { Text = "</table>" });
```

Answer (score 1):

What are you doing is append text;
For example, you need to init and add your controls:

```
TextBox tb1= new TextBox ();
tb1.ID = "tb1"
TextBox tb2= new TextBox ();
tb1.ID = "tb2"


this.Controls.Add(tb1);
this.Controls.Add(tb2);
```

Comment: how to add it to my place holder?

Answer (score 1):

There are several ways to add a control dynamically. But since the question is related to placeholder you do something like below:

```
for (int i=1; i<=3; i++)
{
   Label myLabel = new Label();
   myLabel.Text = "Label_" + i.ToString();
   myLabel.ID = "Label_" + i.ToString();
   PlaceHolder1.Controls.Add(myLabel);
   // Add a spacer in the form of an HTML <br /> element.
   PlaceHolder1.Controls.Add(new LiteralControl("<br/>"));
}
```

> **Note:** Notice that all `runat="server"` control are treated as normal C# class only `HTML(i.e. <br/>)` is used as literals.